# Use UltraVNC with Azure Windows VM

Tags: azure, vnc, azure-virtual-machine

I have a azure VM and when it's running I can connect to it using remote desktop. But when I try to use UltraVNC (already setup) to connect, I just get black screen.
If rdp is also running my UltraVNC works fine.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have an answer to your question! But my first thought on reading this was 'why would you do that' So I thought I'd ask... (I'm sure you have reasons, I'm just curious about them) - P.S. I'm presuming the relevant ports are open?

Comment: This isn't a programming question. Maybe ask on SuperUser? Maybe check which ports you've opened via your endpoints? In any case: Not a StackOverflow question.

Comment: Turns out I simply needed to restart my server.
The reason I needed this was because I had to VPN to use some internal keys, and vpn is not allowed on rdp

Answer (score 0):

to access remote desktop, you need to have RDP endpoint open. once you choose remote desktop option, port 3389 is open to public.

you need to configure UltraVNC endpoint.